# Why is my Case assignment rule not firing

Tags: assignment-rules

I have two case queues, one for New Cases (this is the default on the Support settings page) and one queue for the Unreferenced (cases with no account or contact).
I wrote an assignment rule for the Unreferenced queue

> ISNULL( AccountId ) && ISNULL( ContactId )

The Problem is that these cases are still being assigned to the New Cases queue.

Any advise?

Answer (score 6):

1. What's the order of assignment rules? The first rule that "hits" is
   selected (like in approval processes), make sure your "Unassigned"
   is listed as last option.
2. Are you ticking the checkbox "assign using active assignment rules"?
   It can be missing from the page layout or if you're inserting Cases
   via API you can specify a header / [DML option](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database_dmloptions.htm).
3. Maybe try with ISBLANK instead of ISNULL?
4. Is there any workflow that fires after assignment rules that'd reassign it again?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. @1 I have only one rule with order 1. @2 Yes checkbox is ticked. @3 I tried ISBLANK with no luck. @4 No workflow on Cases

Comment: Running out of ideas :/ As stupid as it sounds - how many processes do you see in Setup -> Assignment Rules and is the one you want marked as active? Can you put a debug log to verify nothing except assignment rules is touching the ownerid? You'll also see the rule evaluation results like with validation rules. Is the queue configured to accept Cases? (shouldn't be selectable in the config if it's not but I'm not sure).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using ISNULL, that function is deprecated and won't work as you would expect in scenarios like this. Use ISBLANK instead.

UPDATE: I just saw your comments, can you post the debug logs for this operation?

Comment: If you look at the comments of the previous answer you can see he already tried ISBLANK with no change to his results.